# Add an obj or array to json string using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array

I have a JSON String and i want to add

```
"23":{"email":"abc333@123.com"}
```

to it but i fail to add a new object like

```js
var json_string = '{"21":{"email":"abc@com"},"22":{"email":"abc2@com"}}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json_string); // to get a object
// Add
var new_obj = {
  23: {"email" : "abc333@123.com"}
};
obj.push(new_obj);
console.log(obj);
```

The result of this get following error message:

> obj.push is not a function

For better understanding: I want to add a object to a json string
I changed the `new_obj` to

```
var new_obj = [{23,[{"email","abc333@123.com"}]];
```

but maybe I have a issue in another part.

Comment: You can't push, you need to specify a key, `obj['key'] = value`.

Comment: You seem to be confused about objects and arrays.  Normally a list of data is stored in an array of objects, like `[{name:"bob", id: 1}, {name: "bill", id: 2}]`  Then you could just push a new object into the array, like you are trying to do.  And use native functions like sort, filter, find to operate on that array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like mentioned, your JSON is not an array.

If you would like to build the object into new_obj, an easy way to add is to use `Object.assign`.

eg.

```js
var json_string = '{"21":{"email":"abc@com"},"22":{"email":"abc2@com"}}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json_string); // to get a object

// Add
var new_obj = {
    23: {"email" : "abc333@123.com"}
};


Object.assign(obj, new_obj);
//obj.push(new_obj);

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) add element to end of array but the `obj` variable isn't array. It is object and you should add property to it as shown in bottom.

```js
var json_string = '{"21":{"email":"abc@com"},"22":{"email":"abc2@com"}}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json_string);
obj[23] = {"email": "abc333@123.com"}
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

The method [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is available only on arrays. You need to create your own:

```js
var json_string = '{"21":{"email":"abc@com"},"22":{"email":"abc2@com"}}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json_string); // to get a object

let pushToObj = function pushToObj(targetObj, newObj) {
    let key = Object.keys(targetObj).sort();
    
    key = Number(key[key.length - 1]);
    
    targetObj[(key + 1).toString()] = newObj;
};

// Add
pushToObj(obj, {"email" : "abc333@123.com"});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

To add on to @Keith 's answer, you can also use the [rest spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) operator to accomplish this:

```js
var json_string = '{"21":{"email":"abc@com"},"22":{"email":"abc2@com"}}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json_string); // to get a object

// Add
var new_obj = {
    23: {"email" : "abc333@123.com"}
};

obj = {...obj, ...new_obj};

console.log(obj);
```